# Swift interoperability with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, namespaces

I've got a Swift struct called `Card`.
I imported a library (by copy pasting the files of that library) in my Xcode project.
In that library there is a Objective-C class named `Card`.

Is there any sort of namespace for all object coming from Objective-C to differentiate those type in my code ?

Example:

```
// This will call my Swift struct
let card = Card()

// This will call the Objective-C class
let card = Namespace.Card()
```

Thanks !

Comment: Well, the Objective-C way to prevent identifier collisions is to prefix classes in a library. You should do this independently of importing it to Swift.

Comment: I don't want to modify the library. As you guessed it's about payment. So if there is an update to this library I will have to change the code again.

I have search for over an hour without any solution. I guess I must rename my Swift struct..

Comment: Prefixes are the pattern to prevent collisions in Objective-C like namespaces in other programming languages. So if one do not use prefixes, you will face the same problems you get, if someone does not use namespaces. Blame him.